# List to array (or?) for graphing purposes

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I would like to know how to take one element from each item in a list and put it into an array for graphing purposes. I was wondering if, since I want to graph each element in each row of the list, could I do it all at once or would I have to separately pull each element out into its own array?

A few lines of a code example is my preferred learning method and would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may have misunderstood what this site is about. It is a Q&A site intended for questions dealing with *specific* programming problems as a way to get a relevant and good online "body of knowledge". For this reason, very broad and unclear questions generally get closed. You may want to [edit] your question to improve it. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can conceptually put the logic to do this in one place.

```
class DataIterator<T> : IEnumerable<T[]> {
    private readonly IList<IList<T>> _lists;

    public DataIterator(IList<IList<T>> lists) {
        Contract.Assert(lists.All(l => l.Count == lists[0].Count));
        _lists = lists; 
    }

    public IEnumerator<T[]> GetEnumerator() {
        var value = new List<T>(_lists.Count);
        for (var i = 0; i < _lists[0].Count; i++) {
            value.AddRange(_lists.Select(t => t[i]));
            yield return value.ToArray();
            value = new List<T>(_lists.Count);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can use it which `foreach` loops.

An example of use:

```
var lists = new List<IList<int>> {
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, 
    new List<int> { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 },  
    new List<int> { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 }
};

var iter = new DataIterator<int>(lists);

foreach (var items in iter) {
    Array.ForEach(items, i => {
        Console.Write("{0:D2} ", i);
    });
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

outputs:

```
01 11 21
02 12 12
...
```

Comment: After re-reading the question, there's some room for interpretation and clarification. I had initially thought it was pretty clear they were talking about how to conceptually organize pulling the same position from multiple collections

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment, just now.  I wasn't critiquing your answer as much as admiring that you managed to make a least some sense of the question.